# How I can zoom an image in GridView with datatype on SQL in binary format (image datatype)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

I have saved an image in SQL database in binary format. Then retrieved that image dynamically on ASPX page with GridView.

Now I want to give a zoom effect on event `click` or `mouseover` in image field.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the the image binary is being rendered inside an img tag?

If so you can add a javascript onclick event that changes the size of the image using css e.g.

```
    <img id="imgCancel" src="Images/cancel.gif" onclick="zoom()" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function zoom() {
            var imgCancel = document.getElementById('imgCancel');
            imgCancel.style.height = '250px';
        }

    </script>
```

This would only increase the size of your thumbnail in gridview though, so might not achieve the intended effect (you would be essentially zooming but the image quality would stay the same).

A better solution would be to have a popup appear on hover/onclick and then use a webservice to retrieve a higher resolution picture from the server.